# Full screen games on dual monitor setup minimized when clicking on second monitor

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, kde, games, plasma

There is an annoying behavior I've noticed on Kubuntu 18 and still on 20, where if I have a game open on one monitor, whether it be in full-screen or full-screen windowed, clicking outside the monitor that the game is running in will minimize the game to the desktop.

I have a hunch it has something to do with how the desktop treats dual monitors as one large screen rather than to discriminate ones, but not sure how to prevent this from happening.